# Some Code Golf links marked as "not secure"

Tags: discussion

I was looking at [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/61115/make-your-language-unusable?noredirect=1&lq=1) question from almost 2 years ago, and wanted to click the first link, which is to this url: https://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2073/25180.

That took me to a site that Chrome (59.0.3071.115) flagged as "not secure" on the grounds of

> NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

The `https:` at the beginning of the url is crossed out as well. The same thing happens for the next link (https://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2447/25180).

I've looked at a few meta links which don't have this issue and seen that rather than start

```
https://meta.codegolf.stackexchange....
```

They start

```
https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange....
```

Did some change take place in the meta url a few years ago leaving links like this abandoned? Does SE's SSL license not cover the `meta.codegolf` domain (and perhaps previously did)? Is this actually any sort of security fault (seems like leaving `https` while still logged in might be, but I don't know enough about it)?

I'm not currently in a situation where I can ignore the warning and go the site anyway (I'll check it out when I can), so I don't know what the behavior is after following the link, but I feel like this in and of itself is worth bringing up anyway.

Comment: Take out the `s` in `https` and it fixes the problem temporarily. We switched from `meta.codegolf` to `codegolf.meta` at some point, and I believe we also switched from `http` to `https`, so something's wonky in there. You can also swap the `meta` and the `codegolf`.

Comment: Yep, as Step Hen said, all of Stack Exchange switched to https a couple months ago. As a side effect, all meta sites became `name.meta` instead of `meta.name`.

Comment: Here's the mother meta post -- https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292058/network-wide-https-its-time

Answer (score 3):

`https://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com` has never worked. Somebody made that edit manually without checking whether it worked. I’ve fixed it.

Comment: For some value of "worked". Actually it always worked fine: the certificate wasn't valid for the name, but at a level of human rather than automatic checking it was good.

Comment: @PeterTaylor: Well, for values of "always" excluding the time (from about two years to a year ago) [when CloudFlare broke it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/265918).

Comment: HTTPS without a valid matching certificate never counts as “working”. It’s worse than broken—it [conditions users to click through certificate mismatch warnings on other HTTPS websites](http://devd.me/papers/alice-in-warningland.pdf) even when they may be under attack.